# turning XML into HTML via xsl causing following issue: key function in xsl does not deliver the desired output

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I was testing a XSL Code and it doesn't deliver the desired output.

XML

```
<data>
  <products>
    <product>
      <id>1</id>
      <description>Tea Leaves - Oolong</description>
      <price>$4.57</price>
      <lead>1</lead>
    </product>
    <product>
      <id>2</id>
      <description>Beans - Navy, Dry</description>
      <price>$11.96</price>
      <lead>1</lead>
    </product>
  </products>
  <customers>
    <customer>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>Alexis Templar</name>
    </customer>
    <customer>
      <id>2</id>
      <name>Valentin McGlue</name>
    </customer>
    <customer>
      <id>3</id>
      <name>Bjorn Saxelby</name>
    </customer>
  </customers>
</data>
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:key name="keyToProduct" match="product" use="lead"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Produktübersicht</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
          rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" 
          crossorigin="anonymous"/>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
          integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" 
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </head>
      <body style="background-color:beige;">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 style="background-color:beige; color:blue;">Produktauswahl der Kunden</h1>
          <h3> Für jeden Kunden wird hier eine Gesamtauflistung aller eingekaufter Produkte veranschaulicht. 
            Ein Kunde kann sowohl kein Produkt oder aber sehr viele gekauft haben.</h3>
          <xsl:for-each select="data/customers/customer">
            <div class="card my-2">
              <div class="card-header">
                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
              </div>
              <div calss="card-body">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs- 
                  target="#exampleModal{id}">
                  <p>Produktübersicht</p>
                </button>
                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal{id}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria- 
                  hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Produktübersicht</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('keyToProduct',id)">
                          <xsl:if test="key('keyToProduct',id)/lead &gt; 0">
                            <ul class="list-group">
                              <li class="list-group-item">
                                <p>Beschreibung:
                                  <xsl:value-of select="key('keyToProduct', id)/description"/></p>
                              </li>
                              <li class="list-group-item">
                                <p>Preis:
                                  <xsl:value-of select="key('keyToProduct', id)/price"/></p>
                              </li>
                              <li class="list-group-item">
                                <p>ID:
                                  <xsl:value-of select="key('keyToProduct', id)/id"/></p>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Schliessen</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>>
```

Desired Output:
The customer with the ID 1 should get both products since they both use the number 1 as their lead. Why is it though, that after i transform the file into html, the output shows only one product for
said customer.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets taken out of context (and not 60+ lines of code). Also include the expected result.

Comment: XML:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<data>
  <products>
    <product>
      <id>1</id>
      <description>Tea Leaves - Oolong</description>
      <price>$4.57</price>
      <lead>20</lead>
    </product>
    <product>
      <id>2</id>
      <description>Beans - Navy, Dry</description>
      <price>$11.96</price>
      <lead>70</lead>
    </product>
</products>
<customers>
    <customer>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>Alexis Templar</name>
    </customer>
    <customer>
      <id>2</id>
      <name>Valentin McGlue</name>
    </customer>
</customers>

Comment: Hi Davud, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't post that much code in a comment. You can edit your own questions to update them with requested content. However, you seem to resolve products of a customer by `key('keyToProduct', id)`. The relation of customers and products is missing in your data. Please show it to us by editing your question.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the hint... I just edited my question, hope it makes sense now.. first time using stack Overflow, sorry about that

Comment: What is the context for `<xsl:for-each select="key('keyToProduct',id)">`?

Comment: Your XML does not appear to have any link between `product` and `customer`. There is one product with a `lead` value of 20 - but no customer with an `id` value of 20. And your XSLT is still incomplete - and invalid to boot: `xsl:key` must be defined outside of any template; `xsl:for-each` must be in a template.

Comment: I have edited the file once more with the same function only on a smaller scale

Answer (score 1):

Consider these two instructions:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('keyToProduct',id)">
  <xsl:if test="key('keyToProduct',id)/lead &gt; 0">
```

I strongly expect that you're expecting the two calls on `key('keyToProduct',id)` to return the same result. But the outer expression changes the context, so `child::id` in the outer expression is different from `child::id` in the inner expression. Replace the inner call with ".". And similarly the other calls on `key()`.